# Submit Slurm job from within a Slurm job

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc, slurm

Say we have a `Slurm` script `foo.bash` like so:

```
#SBATCH <options>

SBATCH bar.bash
```

`bar.bash` is also a `Slurm` script:

```
#SBATCH <options>

<some stuff>
```

When I submit `foo.bash` via `SBATCH`, I'm expecting `bar.bash` to also get submitted (and executed). But that doesn't seem to be happening.

So my question is, how do I launch get a `Slurm` job to successfully submit the `Slurm` job contained within itself? Or is this just not possible?

I am sorry if this is a rather general question, but I haven't been able to find an answer.

Comment: I fail to understand why you need to do that? Anyway you should probably check out job dependency https://hpc.nih.gov/docs/job_dependencies.html

Comment: Note that `bar.bash` will be submitted only when `foo.bash` is **executed**. It will not be submitted at the same time.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. It turns out that I was encountering issues due to a *typo*. So everything is actually working as intended.